# Laravel Eager Loading - Load only specific columns

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to eager load a model in laravel but only return certain columns. I do not want the whole eager loaded table being presented.

```
public function car()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Car', 'id')->get(['emailid','name']);
}
```

I am getting the following error:

log.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::getAndResetWheres()'

Comment: ->get(['col','col2','col3']);

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Make use of the `select()` method:

```
public function car() {
    return $this->hasOne('Car', 'id')->select(['owner_id', 'emailid', 'name']);
}
```

**Note:** Remember to add the columns assigned to the foreign key matching both tables. For instance, in my example, I assumed a `Owner` has a `Car`, meaning that the columns assigned to the foreign key would be something like `owners.id = cars.owner_id`, so I had to add `owner_id` to the list of selected columns;

Comment: Unfortunately thats not working for me. If I add the select() method the relationship is not added. If I remove it I get the entire row.

Comment: Oh, you probably need the foreign key being used as well. For instance, if it'd `id`, you'd need to add `id` to the `select()`'ed columns.

Comment: I've just updated the original answer, check it now. Basically, if `Owner -> Car` relationship is set on `owners.id -> cars.owner_id`, you have to add `owner_id` to the `select()`'ed columns list.

Comment: Spent hours on this, and never thought about having to select the id aswell. But it makes perfectly good sense now. Thanks, i upvoted!

Comment: what if i want to hide the foreign key from result?

Comment: @AdamNick you'll have to filter it before displaying. There's a property that automatically does it for models, I believe it's called `guarded`.

Comment: i figured it, it was hidden property on the model.

Comment: can I put specific conditions like this **return $this->belongsTo('User')->select(['id', 'username'])->where('id', '=', 1);**  or something like this

Answer (score 28):

Also you don't need to specify getting specific columns in the model and the relationship method itself... You can do that whenever you need it... Like this:

```
$owners = Owner::
          with([
              'car' => function($q)
               {
                    $q->select('id', 'owner_id', 'emailid', 'name');
               },
               'bike' => function($q)
               {
                    $q->select('id', 'owner_id', 'emailid', 'name');
               }
          ])->
          get();
```

In this way you can also get all of the columns of the related model if you have ever needed to.

Comment: I'd like to add that this works for `$q->where()` as well if you want to eager load rows with columns that match certain constraints.

Comment: You can also add nested relationships like  `Owner::with(['car' =>... , 'car.drivers' => ...])`  and they will be loaded and structured properly!

Answer (score 21):

In your controller you should be doing something like

```
App\Car::with('owner:id,name,email')->get();
```

Supposing that you have two models defined like below

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Car extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'car';

    public function owner()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Owner', 'owner_id');
    }
}
```

and

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Owner extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'owner';

    public function car()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Car', 'owner_id');
    }
}
```

and you have two tables something like:

```
owners: id | name | email | phone | other_columns...
```

and

```
cars: id | owner_id | make | color | other_columns...
```

Credits go to the docs: [eloquent-relationships#eager-loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) scroll to **Eager Loading Specific Columns**

Answer (score 11):

The easiest thing you can do is go by the documentation and do the following thing for getting only specific columns without any extra line of code or closure. Follow steps,

```
public function car(){
    return $this->hasOne('Car', 'id');
}
```

then when you eager load the relation select only selected columns

```
$owner = $this->owner
->where('id', 23)
->with('car:id,owner_id,emailid,name')   //no space after comma(, ) and id has to be selected otherwise it will give null
```

Hope this works, have a great day.

Comment: This is what i have been looking for! The Laravel docs give NO hint of this syntax, and i only discovered it while debugging why my eagers wouldn't load. The `id` note was the only thing i was missing. You think they'd inject it if it were missing, or at least document its existence. THANK YOU! (Correction: it's documented, but not in the version i'm stuck on - 5.3. Thanks also to @Bogdan for that additional note.)

Comment: Initially I thought it was a bug to always take `id` too in eagers even if we don't want `id` column. But then I realize that it is rather necessary to prevent the `ambiguous` id error of SQL, due to which SQL don't understand which `id` column you were talking about during `joins`. @cautionbug

Comment: In your comment, you mentioned that there should be no space after a comma (,). This insight has helped me understand my mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The answers from [shahrukh-anwar](/a/57218277/258598) and [Bogdan](/a/47901793/258598) are both excellent and led me to solving my version of this problem.

However, there's one critical piece i would add for clarification (even the docs don't mention it).

Take the following, which was still broken for me:

```php
Car::with('owner:id,name,email')->get(['year', 'vin']);
```

You rarely see specific column selection on the primary model (`->get(...)`) so it's easy to forget: your selection needs the foreign key column:

```php
Car::with('owner:id,name,email')->get(['owner_id', 'year', 'vin']);
```

Sure, it seems obvious once you make the mental connection between with using a Closure and this syntax, but still, easy to overlook.

When you have tables with 30+ columns and only need 3 of them, this might keep your memory load down a bit.

Answer (score 3):

It is also possible on eager loading to specify a specific column to load.
Suppose you have this modal class

```
class user extends Model {
  public function car()
    {
      return $this->hasOne('Car', 'id')->get(['emailid','name']);
    }
}
```

if you want to load user with its car you can do this on your controller

```
User::with(['car:id,emailid,name'])->get();
```

:-Note that
DON"T forget to add the foreign key inside the columns you want to get with other wise it will now work. You need a car model as well as the reverse relationship.

For more details you can refer this

[Eager Loading Specific Columns](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-specific-columns)

Answer (score 2):

Using load is even more easy.
If we have a model already instantiated we can put for example having a model User that has a relation of one to many with model Comments and we only want to select from Comment the id and the title

In User model the relation method is

```
public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }
```

In Comment model the relation method is

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

In our controller if we want to recover user with their comments

```
$user = new User();

$user->load('comment:id,title')
```

And we will get the user with comment relation loaded only with id and title :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try **WITH()** & **WHERE()** conditions.

```
$user_id = 1; // for example

Post::with(array('user'=>function($query) use ($user_id ){
            $query->where('user_id','=',$user_id );
            $query->select('user_id','username');
        }))->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to make your relation generic so that can call on your ease.

```
public function car()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Car', 'id');
}
```

and while fetching you can mention columns you need.

```
$owners = Owner::with(['car' => function($query) { // eager loading
            $query->select('emailid','name');
           }
          ])->get();

foreach($owners as $owner){
    $owner->car->emailid;
    $owner->car->name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure to put id column when using eager loading

> Voucher::with(['storeInfo:id,name as branchName,code as
> branchCode'])->get();

IN MODEL

> public function storeInfo()
> {
> return $this->belongsTo(Branch::class,'branch_id');
> }

Answer (score 0):

For Nested Relation, we can use this

```
 Post::with(['user' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('id','company_id', 'username');
        }, 'user.company' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('id', 'name');
        }])->get();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).