# Get Specific Columns Using “With()” Function in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have two tables, `User` and `Post`. One `User` can have many `posts` and one `post` belongs to only one `user`.

In my `User` model I have a `hasMany` relation...

```php
public function post(){
    return $this->hasmany('post');
}
```

And in my `post` model I have a `belongsTo` relation...

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('user');
}
```

Now I want to join these two tables using `Eloquent with()` but want specific columns from the second table. I know I can use the Query Builder but I don't want to.

When in the `Post` model I write...

```
public function getAllPosts() {
    return Post::with('user')->get();
}
```

It runs the following queries...

```
select * from `posts`
select * from `users` where `users`.`id` in (<1>, <2>)
```

But what I want is...

```
select * from `posts`
select id,username from `users` where `users`.`id` in (<1>, <2>)
```

When I use...

```
Post::with('user')->get(array('columns'....));
```

It only returns the column from the first table. I want specific columns using `with()` from the second table. How can I do that?

Comment: This might be obvious to everyone else but me, but on all these answers, you NEED to include the relationship's primary key (usually `id`) as well as any other column, or else your relationship will just return `null`. Took me a minute to figure this one out.

Answer (score 575, accepted):

Well I found the solution. It can be done one by passing a `closure` function in `with()` as second index of array like

```php
Post::query()
    ->with(['user' => function ($query) {
        $query->select('id', 'username');
    }])
    ->get()
```

It will only select `id` and `username` from other table. I hope this will help others.

---

Remember that the **primary key (id in this case) needs to be the first param** in the
`$query->select()` to actually retrieve the necessary results.*

Comment: That's odd, I couldn't get this to work.  As soon as I added in `$query->select('id','username');`, I was getting `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: @user1669496 Do you have defined relations `hasmany` and `belongsto` in your model??

Comment: Weird! still returns all the fields of the user. @AwaisQarni

Comment: @justin share your query

Comment: @AwaisQarni i will give you the laravel forum [click here](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=67637#p67637)

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. Where did you discover this possibility? I didn't find this in the Laravel docs.

Comment: @SymenTimmermans Just trying different possibilities of Eloquent. :-)

Comment: For those who see this, remember that the primary key (`id` in this case) is necessary in the `$query->select()` to actually retrieve the necessary results. I omitted this in my code and couldn't figure out why it wouldn't find any results. Silly me! Hope this helps anyone else with the same problem

Comment: This is a very basic question, but how do I refer to a column from the second table if: $result = Post::with('user')->find(1), then how do I retrieve the user id? ---- $result->user.id ?

Comment: @jasa You can refer to a column from the second table ('users' in this example) like this: $result->user->id;

Comment: @SymenTimmermans it's under http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading constraints. the API docs are pretty poor describing these parameters, and the examples are sometimes hard to find amongst the tutorial style documentation. (I much prefer reference style...)

Comment: I love this solution! I get trouble when I need to get a device detail by using specific device_id, and device activity in specific start time and end time, it works perfectly as I need!

Comment: You can do it with a single command in Laravel 5 see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47238258/2311074

Comment: great, just need to add foreign key, over here its post_id otherwise result will be empty. Mentioning Foreign key is important here. Thanks :)

Comment: Just like @HashaamAhmed I needed to include the foreign key too. If I don't, nothing is returned.

Comment: It is  good but, this keys also sent in API response in JSON how to avoid

Comment: Important!!! needs to include the foreign key (assuming it is user_id in this example). Otherwise it will show null array.

Comment: It still causes problems when trying to select columns from the original model. Using joins solves this and joins are always faster than ORM

Answer (score 293):

You can do it like this since Laravel 5.5:

```
Post::with('user:id,username')->get();
```

Care for the `id` field and `foreign keys` as stated in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

> When using this feature, you should always include the id column and
> any relevant foreign key columns in the list of columns you wish to
> retrieve.

For example, if the user belongs to a team and has a `team_id` as a foreign key column, then `$post->user->team` is empty if you don't specifiy  `team_id`

```
Post::with('user:id,username,team_id')->get();
```

Also, if the user belongs to the post (i.e. there is a column `post_id` in the `users` table), then you need to specify it like this:

```
Post::with('user:id,username,post_id')->get();
```

Otherwise `$post->user` will be empty.

Comment: Don't forget to include the foreign key (assuming it is post_id here) to resolve the relationship, otherwise you will get empty results for your relation.

Comment: This should really be the selected answer. Works like a charm :)

Comment: @Adam, This will restrict columns in the child table, how can I restrict columns from table Parent table along with child table?

Comment: @GauravGenius everything you want to restrict from parant belogns in the `get()` method `Post::with('user:id,username')->get(['age', 'color']);`

Comment: @Kamlesh `Post::with(['user:id,username,team_id', 'othertable:id,horse'])`

Comment: @Adam its weird answer for me because I want to fetch all the records of user table and need 2 fields of other table. I do not want to write all the fields in query as you suggested in your answer. Thanks dear.

Comment: @Kamlesh then go with  `Post::with(['user', 'othertable:id,horse'])`

Comment: @Adam `Post::with('user:id,username')->get(['age', 'color']); ` returns me post with age and color columns but user object is null

Comment: @Imran_Developer whats the primary key on your users table? Maybe `Post::with('user:id,username')->get(['age', 'color', 'id']);` works?

Comment: yes, basically "user_id" was missing. It works now: 
`Post::with('user:id,username')->get(['age', 'color', 'user_id']);`

Comment: I find this as a better solution, but, note that if you have space in between like this: `Post::with('user:id, username, post_id')->get();` it will throw error.

Comment: Also, this doesn't work on hasManyThrough or hasOneThrough relationships

Answer (score 117):

For loading models with specific column, though not eager loading, you could:

In your `Post` model

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User')->select(['id', 'username']);
}
```

Original credit goes to [Laravel Eager Loading - Load only specific columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994253/laravel-eager-loading-load-only-specific-columns)

Comment: But this relation will make it just like hardcoded. In all condition it will always return me these two fields. It may happen that I need more fields in some other situations

Comment: Then you must use the query builder.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in the Laravel 5.3 version? I think they changed it... again.... and now it returns null when I try with this approach

Comment: It's been a while, but you could add a `$fields` parameter.

Comment: @g3mini could you help write an answer on how that would work calling like `$model->user` without invocation?

Comment: Without invocation? So,  `$model->relation->get(['field1', 'field2']);` That should work

Comment: It is not Good idea because if any day if you want full column then you can not get form this. every time you have to modify this.

Comment: can I put specific conditions like this **return $this->belongsTo('User')->select(['id', 'username'])->where('id', '=', 1);** or something like this

Answer (score 105):

When going the other way (hasMany):

```
User::with(['post'=>function($query){
    $query->select('id','user_id');
}])->get();
```

Don't forget to include the foreign key (assuming it is user_id in this example) to resolve the relationship, otherwise you'll get zero results for your relation.

Comment: Yes, exactly, "Don't forget to include the foreign key (assuming it is user_id in this example)"

Comment: you should include  column that defines your relationship in select fields, in this case user_id

Comment: Nice catch brother.

Comment: awesome bro, that use of foreign key is really important, lucky i saw your ans otherwise I would have scratched my head for hours lol. Thanks man!

Comment: This code work for me thank you.

Comment: aha, i missed that important foreign key , and now this code is working

Answer (score 46):

In Laravel 5.7 you can call specific field like this

```
$users = App\Book::with('author:id,name')->get();
```

It is important to add `foreign_key` field in the selection.

Comment: don't forget to add the foreign key field

Comment: Dont forget to notice @hendra1's comment, all foreign key fields are also necessary along with the primary key, otherwise you will get blank collection. Dude saved my time. Thanks

Answer (score 28):

If you want to get specific columns using `with()` in laravel eloquent then you can use code as below which is originally answered by @Adam in his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47238258/7719176) in response of this same question, the answer's main code is as below :

```
Post::with('user:id,username')->get();
```

So i have used it in my code **but it was giving me error of `1052: Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous`,** so if you guys are also facing same problem

Then for solving it **you have to specify table name before the id column in `with()` method as below code**:

```
Post::with('user:user.id,username')->get();
```

Comment: This returns null for me but i didn't know this was possible before! Ok, so I posted prematurley but I did find a result. To use this method (looks much cleaner) you must include the relationship link, for example the ID column when pulling the with data. Without this specifier, you get a null return.

Comment: yeah @Adsy2010, for getting related relationship data you also have to get id column or the primary key or whichever id is responsible for that relationship.

Comment: @Kamlesh `Post::with('user:user.id,username')->get();` this code will return all fields of post model or table and only `id` and `username` field from the `users` table but keep in mind before using `with()` function you should have relationship to relevant table in your model, if you don't have relationship then you can use [join](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#joins) from the query builder.

Answer (score 25):

I came across this issue but with a second layer of related objects. @Awais Qarni's answer holds up with the inclusion of the appropriate foreign key in the nested select statement. Just as an id is required in the first nested select statement to reference the related model, the foreign key is required to reference the second degree of related models; in this example the Company model.

```
Post::with(['user' => function ($query) {
        $query->select('id','company_id', 'username');
    }, 'user.company' => function ($query) {
        $query->select('id', 'name');
    }])->get();
```

Additionally, if you want to select specific columns from the Post model you would need to include the user_id column in the select statement in order to reference it.

```
Post::with(['user' => function ($query) {
        $query->select('id', 'username');
    }])
    ->select('title', 'content', 'user_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: wow, great @jwarshaw, this is what actually I was looking for, this "user_id" really works for me.

Answer (score 16):

In your `Post` model:

```
public function userWithName()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User')->select(array('id', 'first_name', 'last_name'));
}
```

Now you can use `$post->userWithName`

Comment: Really? For me this just returns nothing, i.e. it breaks it?

Comment: you deserve a hug !

Comment: @Sjwdavies you need to add the foreign key in the select as well

Answer (score 7):

There is another alternative you can eager load specific columns

```
public function show(Post $post)
{
    $posts = $post->has('user')->with('user:id,name,email,picture')->findOrFail($post->id);
    return view('your_blade_file_path',compact('posts);
}
```

In your `Post` model you should have `user` relationship also

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo( User::class, 'user_id')->withDefault();
}
```

#### Note: It is mentioned in Laravel docs.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-specific-columns

Comment: can you help with this, it returns me product name but not "user" object:  

$product = Product::where('id', $p_id)->with('user:id,name')->get(['name']);

Comment: @Imran_Developer because you returning name only in get(['name']). do this $product = Product::with('user:id,name')->where('id', $p_id)->get();

Comment: yes dear @Neeraj , but it returns me user object with all columns of product instead of 1 or 2. but I have solved this by using: 
`$product = Product::with('user:id,name')->where('id', $p_id)->select('title', 'content', 'user_id')->get();` . Here "user_id" is important for reference.

Comment: @Imran_Developer ok great.

Answer (score 4):

Note that if you only need one column from the table then using 'lists' is quite nice. In my case i am retrieving a user's favourite articles but i only want the article id's:

```
$favourites = $user->favourites->lists('id');
```

Returns an array of ids, eg:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 7
    [2] => 8
)
```

Comment: it return a collection!

Comment: if you want an array then call `toArray()` !!! 
`$user->favourites->lists('id')->toArray();`

Comment: The query will still get the other columns because the list() method just changes the results array ,so if you just need the 'id' from that table you may want to specify it in the query. It is always a good habit to keep performance in mind when doing queries. Enjoy coding!

Comment: -1 `$user->favourites` will be return `Collection` with all fields selecteds. The correct use is: `$user->favourites()->lists('id')`.

Comment: Selecting everything to later use PHP filtering is a bad idea. It is best to use only the needed fields in Query. It's important to know the difference between `Query\Builder::lists` method and `Collection::lists` method.

Answer (score 3):

If you use PHP 7.4 or later you can also do it using arrow function so it looks cleaner:

```
Post::with(['user' => fn ($query) => $query->select('id','username')])->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue while using belongsToMany relationship with my user model (Laravel 8.x.x).

After a long search and trial and test method. I found out this answer

You have to make sure you are selecting the id's and any foreign keys that would be needed for the relationship from either side of that relationship. This allows Eloquent to match up parents to their children.

Original credit goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/64233242/1551102

So I included

```
Groups::select('groupid')
...
```

And it worked like a charm. Although now I want to know how to hide the groupid field after fetching.
I know I can simply loop through the array and remove it. But is there any other method? potentially a simpler and better one.

Comment: oh thanks bro :) , you really really saved my time

Answer (score 1):

You can also specify columns on related model at the time of accessing it.

`Post::first()->user()->get(['columns....']);`

Answer (score 1):

### You can try this code . It is tested in laravel 6 version.

Controller code

```
 public function getSection(Request $request)
{

  Section::with(['sectionType' => function($q) {
      $q->select('id', 'name');
  }])->where('position',1)->orderBy('serial_no', 'asc')->get(['id','name','','description']);
  return response()->json($getSection);
}
```

Model code

```
public function sectionType(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Section_Type::class, 'type_id');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Be careful that if you don't add the `key` column(s) it won't return anything. If you want to show only the `username` without the `id` you could instead define the `$visible/$hidden` properties within the Model, like so:

#### app/Models/User.php

```
protected $visible = ['username'];
```

Then it will retrieve only `username` column with:

```
Post::with('user')->get();
```

### Hiding the `key` columns:

Alternatively you could hide the `key` column(s) and then retrieve only the columns you wish.

#### app/Models/User.php

```
protected $hidden = ['id'];
```

Specify which columns you want including the `key` or else it won't return anything, but this will actually only return the username, because `id` is `$hidden`.

```
Post::with('user:id,username')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use the `pluck`method on a `Collection` instance:

This will return only the `uuid` attribute of the `Post model`

```
App\Models\User::find(2)->posts->pluck('uuid')
=> Illuminate\Support\Collection {#983
     all: [
       "1",
       "2",
       "3",
     ],
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with conditions.

```
$id = 1;
Post::with(array('user'=>function($query) use ($id){
    $query->where('id','=',$id);
    $query->select('id','username');
}))->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

So, similar to other solutions here is mine:

```
// For example you have this relation defined with "user()" method
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
// Just make another one defined with "user_frontend()" method
public function user_frontend()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User')->select(array('id', 'username'));
}

// Then use it later like this
$thing = new Thing();
$thing->with('user_frontend');

// This way, you get only id and username, 
// and if you want all fields you can do this

$thing = new Thing();
$thing->with('user');
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, when creating a small application based on (a subset of) an existing database, it may be convenient to have *all* models fetch **only the fields you need**; even when loaded by with(). It may ease debugging and avoid confusion, to name an advantage.
The '$visible' attribute (mentioned above) can only be used when the model is converted to array or JSON; see the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json). Otherwise, you could use a combination of [local scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#local-scopes) and a 'public static $fields' property, as in the simplified 'User Class' example below.

```
class User extends Model
{
    public static $fields = [ 'id', 'full_name', 'image' ];
    
    public function scopeFields(Builder $query) : void {
        $query->select(self::$fields);
    }
    
    public function posts(): hasMany {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class)->select(Post::$fields);
    }
}
```

Let's use the well-known class Post too:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public static $fields = [ 'id', 'user_id', 'text', 'created_at' ];
    
    public function scopeFields(Builder $query) : void {
        $query->select(self::$fields);
    }

    public function user(): HasOne {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class)->select(User::$fields);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the functions *scopeFields* are identical, so you should put that in an in-between class.
Anyway, after this you can use the models like:

```
User::fields()->with('posts')->get();
Post::fields()->with('user')->get();
```

All the returned objects will only contain the attributes that are listed in $fields. Tested with Laravel 10.

Answer (score 0):

So this was my old code which is working fine but not as expected

```
$query = Book::withCount('bookReviews')
            ->withAvg('bookReviews', 'rating')
            ->with('createdBy:id,name')
            ->orderBy($sortField, $sortOrder);
```

meaning i am getting result like this

```
..................
{
    "id": 31,
    .....
    "created_by": {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "Darwin Grady"
    },
    .....
},
..................
```

But i only wanted to get the name of the created by user so i had to change it to

```
$query = Book::withCount('bookReviews')
            ->withAvg('bookReviews', 'rating')
            ->addSelect(['createdBy' => User::select('name')->whereColumn('id', 'books.created_by')])
            ->orderBy($sortField, $sortOrder);
```

Now this is the expected result

```
..................
{
    "id": 31,
    .........
    "createdBy": "Darwin Grady"
},
..................
```

Check this out : [Advanced Subqueries](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#subquery-selects)

Answer (score 0):

you must add foreign key in select

for example:

```
   public function expert(): HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id', 'expert_id')
        ->select([
            'id',
            'name',
            'family',
            'image',
        ]);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
EmployeeGatePassStatus::with('user:id,name')->get();
```

Comment: This is the same syntax as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47238258/7404943) (just different names for model and column)