# Selecting columns using 'with()'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Here is my query:

```
return $this->mGalleries->with(array('pictures' => function($query){
        $query->wherePublished(1)->orderBy('sort');
    }))->whereInUse(1)->wherePublished(1)->orderBy('date')->get(array('id', 'title'))->toArray();
```

[I have looked at a question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19852927/get-specific-columns-using-with-function-in-laravel-eloquent) but no luck.

I have tried the suggested:

```
 $query->select('title')->wherePublished(1)->orderBy('sort');
```

But all of the fields continue to come out, although title does appear first when I do this.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: What is the problem? You just said you've tried the suggested and fields continue to come out, and how to fix it, but you don't ask a clear question

Comment: `$query->select('title')->wherePublished(1)->orderBy('sort');` should wotk but `id/primary key` must be in the select list.

Answer (score 0):

You only want to use some columns of the returned set if I understand your question correctly..

I never use `select` on eloquent models because misuse can break the relations between models (necessary columns I.E. `picture_id` are needed to find the picture). So this makes the outcome of the query misleading.

Why do not use it like this:

```
// $galleries = Galleries->with....
$galleries = Gallery::with(array('pictures' => function($query){
        $query->wherePublished(1)->orderBy('sort');
}))->whereInUse(1)
   ->wherePublished(1)
   ->orderBy('date')
   ->get()
   ->toArray();
```

And then when you need for example the title for the first one:
`$falleries[0]['title']`.

You can add the `protected $hidden = array('field/attr', ..);` property in your eloquent model if you want to hide specific attributes from the `toArray()` function.