# Eloquent Specify Relation Columns of belongsToMany relationship

Tags: json, laravel, many-to-many, eloquent, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have tried all kinds of methods of limiting the columns which are returned in my many-to-many relationship, and none seem to work.

**Background - Not really necessary, but to give the big picture**

Essentially, in my app, I want to build a list of contacts for the currently logged in user. `Administrator` and `Billing` users should be able to contact everybody including users of group `Customer`.

`Customer` should only be able to contact `Administrator` and `Billing`.

So my way to tackle this is firstly to determine the groups that the user is in.

```
$userGroups = Sentry::getUser()->getGroups()->lists('name', 'id');
```

Then iterate over the groups, to see if the user is in the group `Administrator` or `Billing` or `Customer` and build the contact groups for that user.

```
foreach($userGroups as $group)
{
    if ($group === 'Administrator' || $group === 'Billing')
    {
        $contactGroups = \Group::with('users')->get(['id', 'name']);
    }
        else if ($group === 'Customer')
        {
            $contactGroups = \Group::where('name', 'Administrator')
                ->orWhere('name', 'Billing')
                ->with('users')
                ->get(['id', 'name']);
        }
        else 
        {
            return Response::json('No Contacts found', 404);
        }
    }
```

The problem - It appears that I am unable to select specific columns to select on belongsToMany relations.

I have tried:

```
$contactGroups = \Group::where('name', 'Administrator')
->orWhere('name', 'Billing')
    ->with(['users', function($q){
        $q->select('id', 'first_name', 'last_name');
    }])
    ->get(['id', 'name']);
```

I have also tried limiting the select within the Group model

```
class Group extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'groups';

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'users_groups')
                ->select('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'telephone');
    }
}
```

Either way, the query runs, but it returns the entire `user` object and completely ignores my selects.

As such, when I return a json response, everything that I do not want is included.

So what I have done as a temporary fix is iterate over each of the users in each of the groups, and unset all the attributes which I do not want.

```
    foreach ($contactGroups as $group)
    {
        foreach($group->users as $user)
        {
            unset($user->persist_code);
            unset($user->created_at);
            unset($user->updated_at);
            unset($user->deleted_at);
            unset($user->last_login);
            unset($user->permissions);
            unset($user->activated_at);
            unset($user->activated);
            unset($user->reset_password_code);
            unset($user->pivot);
        }
    }

return Response::json($contactGroups, 200);
```

This is really clunky, inefficient and seems like a waste of time. Is there a better way of achieving the above?

Comment: Better answers can be read in thread [Get specific columns using “with()” function in Laravel Eloquent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19852927/get-specific-columns-using-with-function-in-laravel-eloquent)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason selecting specific columns with **belongsToMany** is not working. 
But i have found an alternate solution.

There is a provision in laravel, **[Converting to Arrays or json](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#converting-to-arrays-or-json)** that allows you to whitelist/blacklist specific columns when using toArray() or toJson.

To prevent specific fields from appearing in the relation :

```
class User extends Eloquent{

  protected $hidden = array("persist_code","created_at","updated_at","deleted_at","last_login");
}
```

Instead if you wish to allow specific fields :

```
protected $visible = array("Visibile fields");
```

Comment: Yes, your workaround works, and thanks for your answer... however I am then presented with another problem... sometimes, I may need some of these attributes... and blacklisting or whitelisting will ** always ** hide / show them. As such, I need a way of selecting the columns which I require in the first instance.

Comment: e.g. hiding `created_at` in the model will interfere with my `api.v1.admin.user.index` route whereby I do need the `created_at` attribute to be returned in the json response.

Comment: yea i didn't think about the admin page, because thats where you'd want all the results. Its not possible to set the $hidden/$visible properties dynamically either. Any news if the laravel team are planning to fix this or is it going to remain like this ?

Comment: ok so there is one workaround.Only toJson and toArray hide the fields. If you would like to view them u can use model->property to access them. Since the admin page would probably be the only place you'd like to see all the fields, you could use this workaround.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$contactGroups = \Group::where('name', 'Administrator')
->orWhere('name', 'Billing')
->with(['users', function($q){
    $q->get(['id', 'first_name', 'last_name']);
}])
->get(['id', 'name']);
```

or this

```
$contactGroups = \Group::where('name', 'Administrator')
->orWhere('name', 'Billing')
->with(['users:id,first_name,last_name'])
->get(['id', 'name']);
```

Comment: Some explanations can make it more helpful