# Eloquent "select" method not working with using "with" method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

My Village model;

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Village extends Model {
    public function positions() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Map::class, 'id', 'field_id');
    }
}
```

My Map class migration;

```
Schema::create('map_data', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('field_type');
    $table->integer('field_id');
    $table->string('x');
    $table->string('y');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

My "villages" methon on "VillageController" class;

```
public function villages() {
    $villages = Village::with([
        'positions' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('x', 'y');
        }
    ])->get();

    return $villages;
}
```

Result;

```
{
  "villages": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "village 1",
      "created_at": "2016-10-26 18:36:34",
      "updated_at": "2016-10-26 18:36:34",
      "positions": null
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "village 2",
      "created_at": "2016-10-26 18:36:34",
      "updated_at": "2016-10-26 18:36:34",
      "positions": null
    }
  ]
}
```

"Select" method only needs to be mentioned, but not the column returns NULL.

If I delete the `$query->select('x', 'y');` code returns the following results.

```
{
  "villages": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "village 1",
      "created_at": "2016-10-26 18:36:34",
      "updated_at": "2016-10-26 18:36:34",
      "positions": {
        "id": 1,
        "field_type": "1",
        "field_id": "1",
        "x": "21",
        "y": "21",
        "created_at": "2016-10-26 18:36:34",
        "updated_at": "2016-10-26 18:36:34"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "village 2",
      "created_at": "2016-10-26 18:36:34",
      "updated_at": "2016-10-26 18:36:34",
      "positions": {
        "id": 2,
        "field_type": "1",
        "field_id": "2",
        "x": "0",
        "y": "0",
        "created_at": "2016-10-26 18:36:34",
        "updated_at": "2016-10-26 18:36:34"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But I use the `$query->select('x');` code and the result should be the following

resource: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32185643/3287225

Answer (score 33, accepted):

When you try to eagerly load **positions** relation for villages with

```
Village::with(['positions'])->get();
```

3 things happen:

1. Eloquent loads all villages
2. Eloquent loads all positions
3. Eloquent assigns positions to corresponding Village objects using the **field_id** column

In order for it to work, fetched positions need to have **field_id** column fetched, otherwise Eloquent is unable to match them with their corresponding Villages.

When you do

```
$query->select('x', 'y');
```

you're fetching only **x** and **y** columns from your positions table. **field_id** column is not fetched, that's why Eloquent is unable to fetch them with **Village** objects and that's why you're getting **null** in instead of a collection of positions.

Replace

```
$query->select('x', 'y');
```

with

```
$query->select('field_id', 'x', 'y');
```

to make your code work as expected.

Comment: Yes! `$query->select('field_id', 'x', 'y');` is worked successfully.So reference column  to include in "select" query. thanks

Comment: thank you for your answer, means relation field must be define in the select function.

Comment: it also adds reference column to the output. Can we ignore that and only get the ones we want?

Comment: that way very helpful thank you

Comment: nicely explained. thanks