# Select specific columns from both related tables/models

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I have a relationship N x 1, `Post x User`, the Post->User have a relation like the following:

Post.php (model):

```
....
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
....
```

I want to select just the `id` and `username` from User model when I extract each Post, but I also want just the `id` and `title` from the Post (not every column from the Post model).

[With this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19852927/get-specific-columns-using-with-function-in-laravel-eloquent):

```
return Post::with(array('user'=>function($query){
    $query->select('id','username');
}))->get();
```

I can get the `id` and `username` from the `User`, but I'm also extracting all columns from the `Post` model, not what I want, so o tried:

```
return Post::with(array('user'=>function($query){
    $query->select('id','username');
}))->select(['id', 'title'])->get();
```

Although  unsuccessfully, the `User` became null, and I was left with `id` and `title` from the Post.

I'm returning json response, in case that's relevant.

**Note:** I don't want anything 'hard coded' on my Post.php model file, because I may want for the same relation different columns for different situations, so I would like to keep the relation has it is on `Post.php`

Comment: Try this `Post::with(array('user'=>function($query){
    $query->select('id','username');
}))->get(['id', 'title']);`

Comment: @Maraboc, done it the result is the `User` null, I'm not using blade, this is for a json response (if that's relevant)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Post::select('id', 'title', 'user_id')
->with(array('user'=>function($query){
    $query->select('id','username');
}))->get();
```

You need the foreign key to maintain the relationship between the two models.

Comment: That was it, `user_id`, should have been selected as well. thank you

Answer (score 2):

This is usually how I do it.

```
Post::select('id','title','user_id')->with('user:id,username')->get();
```

For this, you need to define the relationship properly and you must select the foreign key form the post table .