# Delete duplicate values in column in display data

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have privot table that have position_id and provider_id. How delete duplicate values that table can look like second table. I would like solve this task by eloquent.
First table display next code:

```
MyTable::with('provider')->with('position')->orderBy('position_id')->get()

position_id provider_id
7            1
7            2
7            3  
9            5
9            6  
10           7


position_id provider_id
7       1
        2
        3   
9       5
        6   
10      7
```

Comment: can you add what is the type of the relation between both tables?, is it many to many ?

Comment: also you want to delete these dublicates from the table or the result ?

Comment: @Hussein I would like delete dublicates from result.

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```
MyTable::with('provider')->with('position')->orderBy('position_id')- 
>groupBy('position_id')->get()
```

You may need to reverse the orderBy and groupBy.

Comment: I get next error in this case Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

Comment: Something like this:  MyTable::with(array('provider'=>function($query){ $query->select('position_id');  
    }))->with('position')->groupBy('position_id')->get(); ..... you might need to play with the syntax a bit, but that should get you fairly close

Comment: Here is a post about adding closure select statements to the eloquent with method. Once you get that part working, you should be able to do a group_by: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19852927/get-specific-columns-using-with-function-in-laravel-eloquent