# Laravel Pivot Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.7  and i have following tables

**category**

```
id | category_name
```

**post_categories**

```
id | category_id | post_id | some other fields
```

**posts**

```
id | post_title
```

i have belongs to many relationship in category Model

```
 public function post(){

        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class,'post_categories','category_id','post_id')
            ->withPivot('col2', 'col3','col4');
    }


$response=Category::with('post')->get();
```

This will return has expected but now i dont need category detail in my response  i mean is it possible to declare relationship in pivot model since i know category_id and i can avoid category detail in my response

my aim is to retrieve all post by category id

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get specific columns using "with()" function in Laravel Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19852927/get-specific-columns-using-with-function-in-laravel-eloquent)

Comment: Are you trying to return only post ID's that relate to this category? Can you clarify what exactly you want to get in response?

Comment: @Aydin4ik.no i need all post detail and some extra pivot row detial

Comment: @Aydin4ik.its not duplicate since post belongs to more than one category

Answer (score 2):

You can use `select()` function on 'Category' to remove unnecessory columns.

Note that 'id' of the category table is important, since it is used in the pivot table as foreign key.

```
// this will only get the id of the category
// and all the post and pivot data.
$response = Category::select('id')->with('post')->get();
```