# Laravel eager loading specific columns error

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-6

I have custom code where I must get specific columns from relation data:

```
$jobs = Job::with('user:id, name')
           ->where('type', 0)
           ->where('status', 1)
           ->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')
           ->get();
```

When I run this code Laravel return me error message:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ' name' in
>   'field list'

How can I solve this error?

Comment: do you have name field in the users table ?

Comment: Here is my `$fillable` variable values: `protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password', 'phone', 'status'];`

Comment: `Unknown column ' name'`, there is blank space `' name'`

Comment: @AndreasHunter Space is a Problem here so remove space only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Specific Columns Using “With()” Function in Laravel Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19852927/get-specific-columns-using-with-function-in-laravel-eloquent)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this code has space `with('user:id, name')`. Problem is space. 
Try this one

```
$jobs = Job::with('user:id,name')
    ->where('type', 0)
    ->where('status', 1)
    ->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 4):

It can be done one by passing a closure function in with() as second index of array like

```
$jobs = Job::with(['user' =>  function($q){
                $q->select('id','name');
            }])->where('type', 0)
               ->where('status', 1)
               ->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')
               ->get();
```