# Convert MYSQL query to Laravel way

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have to convert these queries to Laravel way.

```php
$tqry = "select app_process,end_time,((end_time-".time().")/86400)as remain_day from BYAPPS_apps_data  where mem_id='$valu[mem_id]' limit 1";
                $tresult = $_DB->query($tqry);
                $tmp=$tresult->fetchRow();
                if($tmp[app_process]){
                    $status=$app_process[$tmp[app_process]];
                    if($tmp[app_process]==7&&($tmp[end_time]&&$tmp[remain_day]<=0)) $type="Expired";
                }else {
                    $tqry = "select app_process from BYAPPS_apps_order_data  where mem_id='$valu[mem_id]' order by idx desc limit 1";
                    $tresult = $_DB->query($tqry);
                    $tmp=$tresult->fetchRow();
                    if($tmp[app_process]) $status=$ord_process[$tmp[app_process]];
                    else $status="Not Customer";
                }
```

I set the relation through the models like this.

**UserInfo model**

```php
  public function order()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\AppsOrderData', 'mem_id');
  }

  public function apps()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\AppsData', 'mem_id');
  }
```

**AppsOrderData model (=> Using 'BYAPPS_apps_order_data' table)**

```php
public function userinfo()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\UserInfo', 'mem_id');
  }
```

**AppsData model (=> Using 'BYAPPS_apps_data' table)**

```php
  public function payments()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\AppsPaymentData','mem_id');
  }
```

Then, I tried to convert the original query in `UserInfoController.php` like below.

```php
public function getUserInfoListData()
  {
    $userInfoListData = UserInfo::select('idx',
                                         'mem_id',
                                         'mem_nick',
                                         'mem_name',
                                         'cellno',
                                         'ip',
                                         'reg_date')
                                         ->with('order')
                                         ->with('apps');

    $orderProcess = array('Cancel','Order', 'Confirm Order',
                        'Developing', 'App Uploaded', 'Service end',
                        'Service expired',  '', '', 'Waiting');

    $appsOrderData = AppsOrderData::select('app_process', 'mem_id', 'end_time');

    return Datatables::of($userInfoListData)
            ->setRowId(function($userInfoListData) {
                return $userInfoListData->idx;
            })
            ->editColumn('type', function($eloquent) use ($appsOrderData, $orderProcess) {
              if ($appsOrderData->app_process == 7 && $appsOrderData->end_time <= 0) {
                return "Expired";
              } else {
                return "No Customer";
              }
            })
            ->editColumn('term', function($eloquent) {
              return " (".$eloquent->launch_date." ~ ".now().")";
            })
            ->orderColumn('reg_date', 'reg_date $1')
            ->make(true);
  }
```

However, it doesn't return as I expected, all `type` data return just 'No Customer'.

How can I convert this query as laravel way?

Did I wrong make the relation?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are some mistakes that you have done in your code,

- AppData model doesn't have a user Relationship.
- If you `get()` method to get data , You can do it in this way,

  $userInfoListData= UserInfo ::

  ```
  select('idx','mem_id','mem_nick','mem_name','cellno','ip','reg_date')
      ->with('order')
      ->with('apps')
      ->get();
  ```

For further reference you can use this:
[Get Specific Columns Using “With()” Function in Laravel Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19852927/get-specific-columns-using-with-function-in-laravel-eloquent)

I hope this will help you to solve your  issue- thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have another question. If I set  ``hasMany`` relationship, the other model has to have ``belongsTo``?

Comment: I'm sorry but ``get()`` and add relationship doesn't make the query works. !_!  It keeps error like this ``Property [app_process] doesn't exist ``

Comment: Do the ``with('apps')`` and ``with('order')`` doesn't make the variable ``$userInfoListData`` include the columns from the tables with relationship? How can I compare the ``mem_id`` between the tables and get the ``app_process`` or ``end_time`` columns values?