# Get only one column from relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have found this: [Get Specific Columns Using “With()” Function in Laravel Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19852927/get-specific-columns-using-with-function-in-laravel-eloquent)
but nothing from there did not help.

I have users table, columns: id , name , supplier_id. Table suppliers with columns: id, name.
When I call relation from Model or use eager constraints, relation is empty. When I comment(remove) constraint `select(['id'])` - results are present, but with all users fields.

```
$query = Supplier::with(['test_staff_id_only' => function ($query) {
            //$query->where('id',8); // works only for testing https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads
            // option 1
            $query->select(['id']); // not working , no results in // "test_staff_id_only": []
            // option 2
            //$query->raw('select id from users'); // results with all fields from users table
        }])->first();
        return $query;
```

In Supplier model:

```
public function test_staff_id_only(){
        return $this->hasMany(User::class,'supplier_id','id')
            //option 3 - if enabled, no results in this relation
            ->select(['id']);// also tried: ->selectRaw('users.id as uid from users') and ->select('users.id')
}
```

How can I select only id from users?

Comment: see @OMR answer and not forget "eager loading won't work without foreingkey relation"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in you relation remove select(['id'])

```
public function test_staff_id_only(){
        return $this->hasMany(User::class,'supplier_id','id');
}
```

now in your code:

```
$query = Supplier::with(['test_staff_id_only:id,supplier_id'])->first();
```

Comment: This is what suggested Tim and it not works ( I mean it not limiting columns, and shows all columns from users table )

Comment: this column 'supplier_id' what is his table name?

Comment: if I remove select(['id']) - i get all columns.

Comment: users: id, name, supplier_id  and suppliers table: id, name

Comment: eager loading won't work without foreingkey relation

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Ah, so you need both `:id,supplier_id`; that makes sense. So my approach was still correct, but slightly off. Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

There's a pretty simple answer actually. Define your relationship as:

```
public function users(){
  return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'supplier_id', 'id');
}
```

Now, if you call `Supplier::with('users')->get()`, you'll get a list of all suppliers with their `users`, which is close, but a bit bloated. To limit the columns returned in the relationship, use the `:` modifier:

```
$suppliersWithUserIds = Supplier::with('users:id')->get();
```

Now, you will have a list of `Supplier` models, and each `$supplier->users` value will only contain the ID.

Comment: Not working. "users" are empty , and checked again with Heidi: user with id 8 is having supplier_id 1.

Comment: if I remove    ":id" from "users:id" - it shows user data with all users columns

Comment: Maybe needs to be `users:supplier_id`? Either way the principle stands; to limit the columns returned from the relationship, you use the `:` modifier.

Comment: No. I need id's of users (theirs ids)

Comment: if make pivot table with columns user_id and supplier_id and use in model this:  public function staff_id_only()    {  return $this ->belongsToMany('App\User')->select(['users.id']); }      then it works! But I want to remove that pivot table.   Also tried  ->select(['users.id'])   in my attempts (with hasMany) but not successfull

Comment: Use ```pluck()``` to achieve this, ex: ```Suppliers::all()->pluck('id')```. This will return all suppliers ids. See more in the Laravel doc: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-pluck

Comment: @ettdro no, I want users id's in relation , not id of Supplier.