# Laravel select specific columns with Eloquent while eager loading

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 8. I have 2 tables and trying to select specific columns from both tables using Eloquent:

```
$ids = [1, 8, 14];
$food = Food::with(
            ['animals' => function ($query)
            {
                $query->select('id', 'name');
                $query->where('status', 1);
            }])
            ->select('id', 'type')
            ->whereIn('id', $ids)
            ->where('status', 1)
            ->get();
```

However, if I add a `select` method to the `Food` model, Laravel returns `null` for the `animals` table.

If I don't specify selects on the `Food` model, Laravel returns everything from the `Food` model and `id`, `name` from the `animals` table.

How can I select both from the `Food` and the `Animal` table simultaneously, while using Eager Loading?

Comment: you have to make sure to also select any foreign keys needed for the relationship

Comment: can you share `animals` relationship function?

Comment: @lagbox This was the problem, thank you so much for pointing it out. I left out one of the foreign keys from the select query! If you create an answer, I'll approve it!

Comment: which table has the foreign key in this scenario, btw?

Comment: @lagbox The `animals` table. I added it to the `food` table's select and it worked instantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make sure you are selecting the id's **and** any foreign keys that would be needed for the relationship from either side of that relationship. This allows Eloquent to match up parents to their children.

Answer (score 0):

lagbox's suggestion actually pointed me in the direction of the solution to my issue, which was similar to the original issue. I also had a query with a select-statement and was trying to eager load a relationship. In my case the problem lay with aliasing the id that was needed to load the relationship.

So originally my code looked like this: `Question::query()->select(['questions.id AS question_id', [...])->with('translations')->get()`. It was actually the "AS question_id" part that led to the relationship data turning up as empty arrays. Once I deleted that alias and selected it as just 'questions.id', the relationship data could be retrieved again.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one, specify the table in select.

```
Food::with(['animals' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('status', 1);
        }])
        ->select('food.id', 'animals.type', 'food.type')
        ->whereIn('id', $ids)
        ->where('status', 1)
        ->get();
```