# Get specific fields from both parent and child models

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1, eager-loading

I am trying to retrieve a model instance along with its related one so that only certain fields are retrieved from **both**. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19852927/get-specific-columns-using-with-function-in-laravel-eloquent) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994253/laravel-eager-loading-load-only-specific-columns) questions answer how to do that for *related* models and it works well for me:

```
$hash = \Post::whereId(1075)
                        ->with(['thread' => function($query) {
                            $query->select('id', 'title');
                        }])
                        ->first()
                        ->toArray();
print_r($hash);
Array
(
    [id] => 1075
    [title] => Blablablablam,
    [text] => Blablablablablablabl,
    [created_at] => 2015-10-17 13:00:00
    [updated_at] => 2015-10-17 13:00:00
    [thread] => Array
        (
            [id] => 180
            [title] => Blablablablam
        )
)
```

However, if I try to limit the fields for the `Post` model as well, then the `Thread` data is not retrieved at all:

```
$hash = \Post::whereId(1075)
                        ->with(['thread' => function($query) {
                            $query->select('id', 'title');
                        }])
                        ->addSelect('title')
                        ->first()
                        ->toArray();
print_r($hash);
Array
(
    [title] => Blablablablam,
    [thread] => 
)
```

So, how to retrieve only certain fields from both the main and related models?

**UPDATE**

Here is what worked for me after I saw the cresjie's answer:

```
$hash = \Post::whereId(1075)
                        ->with(['thread' => function($query) {
                            $query->select('id', 'title');
                        }])
                        ->addSelect('title', 'thread_id')
                        ->first()
                        ->toArray();
print_r($hash);
Array
(
    [title] => Blablablablam,
    [thread_id] => 180,
    [thread] => Array
        (
            [id] => 180
            [title] => Blablablablam
        )
)
```

The only thing that still puzzles me is that the foreign key (`thread_id`) needs to be specified explicitly even though is it already specified in the `Post` class:

```
public function thread()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Thread::class, 'thread_id');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `Thread` data was not retrieved because you need also to select the foreign keys in your `Post`

Comment: Wow, that's it, thank you! However, the foreign key is already defined in the `Post` model's `thread` method. Is there any way to get Laravel to add it to the `select` call automatically in order to avoid specifying the foreign key twice?