# Get only the IDs using with, Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I want to get all IDs from `with`, at the moment I get all data (`id`, `name`, `pivot`, etc..)

```
$teacher = Teacher::where('id', $id)->with(['subjects' => function($q) {
      $q->select('id')->value('id');
}])->orderByDesc('id')->first();
```

I tried:

```
$q->pluck('id')->all();
$q->pluck('id');
$q->get('id');
$q->value('id');
$q->pluck('id')->all();
```

At the end result I only idee an array of ids `[1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: `$q->select('subjects.id')->value('subjects.id');`

Comment: Same output.. [ { "id": 33, "pivot": { "teacher_id": 34, "subject_id": 33 } } ]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Eager Loading - Load only specific columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994253/laravel-eager-loading-load-only-specific-columns)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely much easier to come at this query from the reverse.  I.E. if you are after only the ids of those Subjects under a particular Teacher, grab from the Subjects table rather than a subquery at the Teacher level.

For a simple relationship, something like:

```
$subject_ids = Subject::where('teacher_id', $id)->pluck('id');
```

Or if it is a full pivot relationship you could go to the table itself, similar to:

```
$subject_ids = \DB::table('subject_teacher')->where('teacher_id', $id)->pluck('subject_id');
```

The last example assumes a lot in terms of how you set this up, but hopefully gives you an idea on how you might do this with a simpler query.

HTH