# Laravel - how to makeVisible an attribute in a Laravel relation?

Tags: laravel

I use in my model code to get a relation

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    // ...
    public function extensions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Extension::class, 'v_extension_users', 'user_uuid', 'extension_uuid');
    }
    // ...
}
```

The **Extension** has field **password** hidden.

```
class Extension extends Model
{
    // ...
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
    ];
    // ...
}
```

Under some circumstances I want to **makeVisible** the password field.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I got the idea from https://stackoverflow.com/a/38297876/518704

Since my relation model `Extension::class` is called by name in my code `return $this->belongsToMany(Extension::class,...` I cannot even pass parameter to it's constructor.

So to pass something to the constructor I may use static class variables.

So in my `Extension` model I add static variables and run makeVisible method.
Later I destruct the variables to be sure next calls and instances use default model settings.

I moved this to a trait, but here I show at my model example.

```
class Extension extends Model
{
    public static $staticMakeVisible;

    public function __construct($attributes = array())
    {
      parent::__construct($attributes);

      if (isset(self::$staticMakeVisible)){
          $this->makeVisible(self::$staticMakeVisible);
      }
   }
.....

    public function __destruct()
    {
      self::$staticMakeVisible = null;
    }

}
```

And in my relation I use something like this

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
...
    public function extensions()
    {
        $class = Extension::class;
        $class::$staticMakeVisible = ['password'];

        return $this->belongsToMany(Extension::class, 'v_extension_users', 'user_uuid', 'extension_uuid');
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 15):

[`->makeVisible([...])`](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_makeVisible) should work:

```
$model = \Model::first();
$model->makeVisible(['password']);

$models = \Model::get();
$models = $models->each(function ($i, $k) {
    $i->makeVisible(['password']);
});

// belongs to many / has many
$related = $parent->relation->each(function ($i, $k) {
    $i->makeVisible(['password']);
});

// belongs to many / has many - with loading
$related = $parent->relation()->get()->each(function ($i, $k) {
    $i->makeVisible(['password']);
});
```

Comment: I tired this approach but could not find what I have to write to return from my `public function extensions()` a result with visible password. 
If I return  `Model::get()` Collection instead of a `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany` from the method it brokes all other my things.

You offer to change the type of the returning relation data. Here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships it returns something like         `return $this->belongsTo('App\User');` but not         `return $this->belongsTo('App\User')->get();`

Comment: Updated my answer. Both last 2 are loading from a relationship. First one assumes you have loaded your relationship before, second one loads it on the go.

Comment: I stiil don't see how I can modify my  `public function extensions()` to get the password field visible.

Comment: Well you can't. You can't make fields visible on query (relationships return query, not model), this all happens on model.

Answer (score 0):

The highest voted answer didn't seem to work for me (the `relations` attribute seems to be a [protected array](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.php#L29) now so can't be used as a collection in @DevK's answer), I instead used:

```
$parent->setRelation('child', $parent->child->first()->setVisible(['id']));
```

Answer (score -1):

This is working for me

```
$user=User::select(['id','password as user_password'])->first();
```

Comment: Not an answer for the actual question.