# Laravel how to make visible a hidden attribute of relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 4 table as following:
1- proposals (belongs to projects)
2- projects (has many proposals, and belongs to business)
3- businesses (has many projects, belongs to user)
4- users (has one business)

In users I've set `email` as hidden field, What I want is to take count of today proposals for each project, and group them based on business, then I should mail count of proposal for each projects of business. Suppose business A has posted two project and received 5 proposal for both projects (3 for one, and 2 for the other). My current query not group data based on business, it only group data based on project. My question is:
1- How can I achieve this to get count of data based on `business, and project`
2- How can I make visible `email` field of `users` model.

```
 $data = Proposal::toDay()
    ->selectRaw('count(*) AS cnt, project_id')  
    ->with([
        'project:id,title,business_id',
        'project.business' => function($query) {
            return $query->select(['id', 'name', 'owner_id']);
        },
        'project.business.owner' => function($query) {
            return $query->select(['id','first_name','last_name','email']);
        }
    ])
    ->groupBy('project_id')
    ->get();
```

Current output is like this:

```
array:3 [
0 => array:4 [
"cnt" => 1
"project_id" => 1
"submission_date" => ""
"project" => array:5 [
  "id" => 1
  "title" => "HRMIS System"
  "business_id" => 2
  "liked" => false
  "business" => array:4 [
    "id" => 2
    "name" => "Company A"
    "owner_id" => 5
    "owner" => array:3 [
      "id" => 5
      "first_name" => "Mobasher"
      "last_name" => "Fasihi"
    ]
  ]
]
]
1 => array:4 [
"cnt" => 1
"project_id" => 2
"submission_date" => ""
"project" => array:5 [
  "id" => 2
  "title" => "Senior Software Developer"
  "business_id" => 1
  "liked" => false
  "business" => array:4 [
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "Company B"
    "owner_id" => 2
    "owner" => array:3 [
      "id" => 2
      "first_name" => "John"
      "last_name" => "Richard"
    ]
  ]
]
]
2 => array:4 [
"cnt" => 1
"project_id" => 4
"submission_date" => ""
"project" => array:5 [
  "id" => 4
  "title" => "100 Mac-Book Pro"
  "business_id" => 1
  "liked" => false
  "business" => array:4 [
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "Company B"
    "owner_id" => 2
    "owner" => array:3 [
      "id" => 2
      "first_name" => "John"
      "last_name" => "Richard"
    ]
  ]
]
]
]
```

What I expect is:

```
[
  0 => [
    "cnt" => 1
    "submission_date" => "",
    "project" => [
      "id" => 1,
      "title" => "HRMIS System",
      "business_id" => 2,
      "liked" => false,
      "business" => [
        "id" => 2
        "name" => "Company A"
        "owner_id" => 5,
        "owner" => [
          "id" => 5
          "first_name" => "Mobasher",
          "last_name" => "Fasihi",
          "email" => "mobasher@test.com"
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ],
  1 => [
    "cnt" => 2
    "submission_date" => "",
    "project" => [
      "id" => 2
      "title" => "Senior Software Developer"
      "business_id" => 1,
      "liked" => false,
      "business" => [
        "id" => 1,
        "name" => "Company B",
        "owner_id" => 2,
        "owner" => [
          "id" => 2,
          "first_name" => "John",
          "last_name" => "Richard",
          "email" => "john@test.com"
        ]
      ]
    ],
    "project" => [
      "id" => 4
      "title" => "100 Mac-Book Pro"
      "business_id" => 1
      "liked" => false
      "business" => [
        "id" => 1,
        "name" => "Company B",
        "owner_id" => 2,
        "owner" => [
          "id" => 2
          "first_name" => "John"
          "last_name" => "Richard",
          "email" => "john@test.com"
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: Is email field included in `hidden` property under user model? also check your `owner` relation if you are doing some select there itself

Comment: @Viney Yes email is included in `hidden` property of user model, and I have no selection in `owner` relation

Comment: I see, then you'll need to use `makeVisible` ref:https://stackoverflow.com/q/44167733/6160662

Comment: @Viney Thanks, its working now

Comment: @Viney Still want to find a way to count by business id as well

Comment: Please post it in a new question