# Laravel: Use makeVisible() after a hasMany() call

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm using lumen to develop a REST API. I used for that 2 models `User` and `Post`. In my `User` model I can get all the user's posts using the `hasMany()` method:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
  // ...
  public function posts()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
  }
  // ...
```

It's really helpfull to get all my user posts:

```php
return response()->json(User::find($id)->posts, 200);
```

Problem is that the `Post` model has some hidden attributes that are not shown in the response (which is the normal behaviour) but for some request I need to return them. For this purpose, laravel provide a method called [makeVisible()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-collections#method-makeVisible). So I decide to used it in my `posts()` method:

```php
  public function posts()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post')->makeVisible(['hiddenAttribute', ...]);
  }
```

But unfortunately things aren't as simple as that and I get this error:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::makeVisible()

Has anyone an idea how I can use this both methods together?

Comment: Something like this.   `User::find($id)->posts ->transform(function ($post) {
    $post->makeVisible(['hiddenAttr']);
    return $post;
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

option 1:

like [porloscerros Ψ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7498116/porloscerros-%ce%a8) said in comment, you have to iterate over all your model collection and make visible

```
$value = User::find($id)->posts->each(function ($post, $key))
  {
    $post->makeVisible(['hiddenAttribute',...]);
  }
); 

return response()->json($value, 200);
```

option 2:
extend model class to fit your need... see:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44169024/10573560